# How can I add row headers in MDX?

Tags: sql, database, mdx, cube

I have a MDX query that I want to use to upload some Cube data to a SQL database. For this purpose, I want all rows to have a header, something is not done by default in MDX.

Could someone modify the following MDX query to add the headers for the two leftmost columns in the resulting table?

Query:

```
SELECT                                                                                  
NON EMPTY                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                         
  [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity],  
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]                                                 
} ON COLUMNS,      
NON EMPTY                                                                                
{ (                                                                                      
  [Customer].[Education].[Education].ALLMEMBERS *
  [Customer].[Home Owner].[Home Owner].ALLMEMBERS
) } ON ROWS                                                                                                                                             
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Resulting table:

[image: Query result]

Thanks

Comment: Unless SSMS is your final end user client tool I wouldn't worry about how it renders the results. What's your real client tool? Does it exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: The final goal is to periodically query the Cube data and Insert it into a SQL database. Wouldn't it be easier having the right headers?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the query through a SQL Server [linked server connected to SSAS](http://blog.datainspirations.com/2010/11/30/creating-a-linked-server-for-analysis-services/) would be a logical choice for your scenario of inserting the results of a query against the cube into SQL Server. That exact query will have column headers when read through a linked server. So I wouldn't worry about SSMS MDX query window rendering the query results as a Cellset rather than a Rowset.

Answer (score 0):

Greg's answer is correct.
We have found issues (re speed & blocking) with linked servers to SSAS and use the following CLR solution:

https://olapextensions.codeplex.com/

You can then do the following with the stored procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE #results(
   Education     VARCHAR(250),
   Owner         VARCHAR(250),
   OrderQuantity FLOAT,
   SalesAmount   FLOAT
);

DECLARE @Server NVARCHAR(30) = 'localhost'
DECLARE @Database NVARCHAR(50) = 'AdventureWorksDW2012Multidimensional-EE';
DECLARE @MDX NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'
SELECT                                                                                  
NON EMPTY                                                                                
{                                                                                                                                         
  [Measures].[Internet Order Quantity],  
  [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]                                                 
} ON COLUMNS,      
NON EMPTY                                                                                
{ (                                                                                      
  [Customer].[Education].[Education].ALLMEMBERS *
  [Customer].[Home Owner].[Home Owner].ALLMEMBERS
) } ON ROWS                                                                                                                                             
FROM [Adventure Works]
'

INSERT INTO #results
EXEC ExecuteOLAP @Server, @Database, @MDX;

SELECT *
FROM   #results;
```